# Install Chrome extensions on a work computer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hope I ask this in the right place.

Is it safe to install Chrome extensions on a work computer that deals with somehow sensitive data and internal pages ? Are there any safety concerns I should consider ?

For example I would like to install this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are some Chrome Extensions that are blocked in some work computers because of the permissions the extension requests.

Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2yTVWdfC4Gg), some installed extensions invade privacy and worsen the browsing experience.

> Here are a few options for you:
>
> - If it is an extension you wrote yourself, you can upload it to the webstore and publish it in a "hidden" state so that only people with the link, or people in a set of trusted tester users, can install it.
> - If it is an extension from a 3rd party software company, contact their support to point them at our [blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) and ask them if they can migrate their extension to the webstore.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting.